# jquery move div above others

Tags: jquery, html, move

How can I move `.2` between the two `.1` elements within `div#one` in my HTML sample:

```
<div id="zero">
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="1"></div>
</div>

<div id="one">
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="1"></div>
   <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried `.prev()` but this does not work. It puts the `.2` in the `div#zero`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `insertafter()` method, along with the `:first` selector to place the content in the required position. Try this:

```
$('#one .2').insertAfter('#one .1:first');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYnw5/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one .2').after($('#one .2').prev());
```